# Complexity and binary tries

Tags: binary-tree, complexity-theory

I have a big problem understanding complexity and especially with `binary trees`.

For example, I know that when we have a problem, with say the problem's size is `x=log2(sizeofarray)` but I don't understand where this `log2` comes from?

Answer (score 1):

It's log<sub>2</sub> because each level of tree splits your problem into two.

For instance, consider this set of data:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
```

The first level could be

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
```

the second level:

```
{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 }
```

the third level:

```
{ 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 }, { 6 }, { 7 }, { 8 }
```

---

Here with 8 values, log<sub>2</sub>(8) = 3, and there are 3 levels in the tree.

---

Also see these other StackOverflow questions for more:

- "[*Why is the height of a balanced binary tree log(n)? (Proof)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14539141/1364007)" - the answer follows a similar vein to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840486/1364007) that [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443) posted on this question.
- "[*Search times for binary search tree*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/526718/1364007)" - contains some pretty ASCII art, and examines best/worst case scenarios.

Comment: thank you, and what about this best / worst case scenario? could we say that if the element we're searching is at the total bottom the comlexity is log2(size) and if it's at the top it's O(1) ?

Comment: worst case is you have to travel through the *whole* tree, that gives you a complexity of O(size) where size is the number of nodes in the tree, no log in that case

Comment: As @user2314737 correctly points out, the worst case is a is a [degenerate tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), which is basically a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: Nice answer (both and all of you guys). Hopefully the OP comes back someday!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a binary search as the easy example. Say you have a sorted list of 64 elements, and you're searching for a particular one. In each iteration, you halve the dataset. By the time your dataset has 1 element, you have halved it 6 times (count the arrows, not the numbers):

```
64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

The reason for this is the fact that `64 = 2 ^ 6`, where `2` is the base (you divide the dataset in 2 parts in each iteration), and the exponent is `6` (as you get to the bottom in 6 iterations). There is another way to write this, since exponentiation has its inverse in logarithm:

```
64 = 2 ^ 6
6 = log2 64
```

So we can see that the number of iterations scales with the base-two logarithm of the number of elements.